# Laravel 8 has many problems pulling data in the use of the associated table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am developing a project. I have made associations using many variants, but I cannot pull the data. Can you help me?

**user table:** id, first_name, last_name, email, password, image, adress
**user_teammates table:**  id, user_id(foreign user table id) , teammate_id (foreign user table id)

**User Model**

```
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_teammate', 'teammate_id','user_id');
}
```

**UserTeammate Model**

```
public function users_relate()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_teammates', 'user_id','teammate_id');
    }
```

**User Controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        $teams = UserTeammate::find(Auth::id())->users_relate()->get();
        return view('user.user')->with('teams', $teams);
    }
```

**Output**

```
Error
Call to a member function users_relate() on null
```

Comment: Make sure you are logged-In, otherwise `Auth::id()` returns null

Comment: it means that you are trying to call user_related() relation method on null.
make sure there must exist the userTeammate record

Comment: check that are you getting user data or not, test as `$teams = UserTeammate::find(Auth::id())->first();` then if found user then you can use also as `$teams->users_relate`

Comment: @sta Yes i logged in

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Tried but still getting the same error :(

Comment: did you find data in `$teams` ?

Comment: @Devsi Odedra When I write to the screen with dd, I still get an error

Comment: just `dd` this `$teams = UserTeammate::find(Auth::id());`

Comment: @Devsi Odedra Yes it is now. But a blank value returned. I did the first thing you said.I typed 1 for trial purposes instead of Auth :: id (), but when you enter user number 66, it gives an error. It is a very interesting situation. While recording, I can not understand it did it smoothly.

Comment: if you directly enter user id in `find(66)` it should give you record if exist in DB

Comment: @DevsiOdedra All data of user 66 exist in the database, but it does not return their values at all. I'm testing from the account of user 66.

Comment: @Devsi Odedra I do not have a problem with the users I created with Seeder, but the users I registered from the admin panel have this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember_token, created_at, updated_at fields were missing in the users I created over Seeder and when they created records on the site. When I filled them in, my problem was solved.